# ssh under tmux always asks for password

Tags: ssh, macos, tmux

Normally I give my passphrase for the private key on the first `ssh` invocation and then I am not asked for the passphrase (in this and all other bash sessions).

However, under `tmux`, I am asked for the passphrase over and over even in the same `bash` (same `tmux` pane).

I think the problem originated with the Sierra.

**How do I avoid having to enter my passphrase repeatedly under `tmux`?**

PS. `ssh-add -l` prints `The agent has no identities.` both with and without `tmux`.

PPS. `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` names an existing socket under `/private/tmp...`.

Comment: Do you see the key in the `ssh-add -l` output? If not, the key is not in keyring or the `tmux` does not see the keyring (for some reason).

Comment: @Jakuje: `ssh-add -l` prints `The agent has no identities.` both with and without `tmux`.  but without `tmux` I am not asked for password!

Comment: I have the same issue. I also notice that enabling agent forwarding will set `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on the first remote machine but will not forward credentials properly.

Answer (score 3):

Open a new terminal window and run the following commands:

```
$ tmux new -s temp
$ ssh-agent
$ ssh-add
```

That seems to have fixed the issue for me; new tmux sessions now no longer ask me for my ssh key passphrase.

Comment: yes, of course that works. the question is why this was not necessary before.

Comment: @sds it looks like your question was actually how to avoid it - soooo your question was answered. And helped me too. :thumbs_up:

Comment: What do these commands do, and why does this work?